# Fragen den Konjunktiv betreffend

Tags: subjunctive

1) Gibt es hinsichtlich der Bedeutung einen Unterschied zwischen

*Man mag glauben, dass...*

und

*Man möchte glauben, dass*... ?

2) Kann man ein einen Nebensatz einleitendes *dass* durch einen Konjunktiv ersetzen? Etwa

*Man mag glauben, dass es so ist.*

durch

*Man mag glauben, es sei so.*

Was ist mit

*Man mag glauben, dass es so sei.*?

Gibt es Gründe, eine Variante der anderen vorzuziehen? Ist eine Aneinanderreihung von Hauptsätzen ästhetischer, als sich dem Überfluss einleitender *dass* preiszugeben?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Den gibt es: Obwohl sowohl *mag* als auch *möchte* Formen von "mögen" darstellen, ist ihre Bedeutung unterschiedlich.

Die Verwendung von "mag" als Modalverb entspricht in ihrer Bedeutung dem englischen "may": sie drückt eine Vermutung oder ungewisse Annahme aus. "Man mag glauben..." entspricht ungefähr "Man glaubt vielleicht/womöglich..."

"möchte" hingegen wird hier durchaus in der auch in der Standardsprache gewohnten Bedeutung verwendet. Obwohl "möchte" eine Konjunktivform ist, ist ihre Bedeutung im Grunde indikativisch und dient zur Äußerung von Wünschen oder hier einer gewissen Neigung. Der Duden führt auch einen ähnlichen Satz unter dieser Bedeutung von "mögen":

> **Konjunktiv II meist in der Bedeutung eines Indikativ Präsens** den Wunsch haben [...] *man möchte meinen (ist, wäre geneigt anzunehmen), dass er es absichtlich getan hat*

2) *Man mag glauben, es sei so.* und *Man mag glauben, dass es so sei.* sind völlig äquivalente Formulierungen. Die Möglichkeit, statt Nebensätzen auch einfache Hauptsätze zur Wiedergabe der Rede zu benutzen, besteht für viele Sprechverben, z.B. *sagen*, *behaupten*, *meinen*, auch *denken*...

Die Entscheidung für die eine oder die andere Form geht wohl auf stilistische Erwägungen zurück, insbesondere den Sprechrhythmus und das Bestreben, das Satzgefüge nicht durch übermäßigen Gebrauch von Nebensätzen unnötig zu verkomplizieren.

Der Konjunktiv I, der hier zur Wiedergabe der Gedanken und im Allgemeinen zur Wiedergabe von Rede verwendet wird, wird im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch zunehmend seltener. Deswegen klingt für mich auch die Form "Man mag glauben, dass es so ist." bzw. "Man mag glauben, es ist so." akzeptabel. Der Konjunktiv I klingt in zunehmendem Maße bildungssprachlich.

Comment: Kleine Randnotiz: *möchte* wird im Grunde verwendet wie eine höflichere Form von *wollen*.